# How to use the jquery jpagination plugin

Tags: jquery, pagination, jquery-pagination

does anyone out there know how to use the jquery recordset pagination plugin called jpagination? I have searched the net but there is no substantial info, all it says is use

`$(elementID).paginate()`, what element are they referring to, is it a table, div where the table is, what. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

With pagination plugins you select a parent element and the paginator automatically selects next child elements to page. So, if you have....

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

You would paginate on the "wrapper" element.

```
$('#wrapper').paginate();
```

I'm not certain what the restrictions are on this particular plugin but I would think it would adapt to nearly any parent->children DOM relationship, not just divs. There's documentation on their web site and you can always browse the source of their working demos.